# Google Cloud DNS - How to point a subdomain to onother instance (also on Google Cloud)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns

I have 2 distinct instances on Google Compute Engine.

On the first (lets name it instance1) I have hosted a website (with domain name instance1domain.com linked to it and static IP) and everything is working great.

On the second instance I have a web app that I want to be a subdomain of the site on the first instance (like app.instance1domain.com).

Both my instances are on the same zone with internal IP's from the same subnetwork (in Google Compute Engine).

**How ca I map the second instance in Google Cloud DNS in such way that it becomes a subdomain for the site hosted on the first instance ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create the A record for the second instance with the name `app.instance1domain.com` and use the IP address of the second GCE instance.

While some extra DNS records are needed if you want to make a second DNS managed zone into [a delegated subdomain of the first](https://serverfault.com/q/252749/95570), you don't need to do that to create a subdomain entry in the same DNS managed zone.

So a single managed zone can have entries for all of the following:

1. `example.com`
2. `xyz.example.com`
3. `abc.xyz.example.com`
4. `abc.def.example.com`

In the fourth case, you don't need to create an entry for `def.example.com` in order to have `abc.def.example.com`; creating the subdomain `abc.def.example.com` implicitly creates `def.example.com` as what is called an “empty non-terminal.”

Note that you cannot create a domain name that is not a subdomain of the zone's domain, so for example, it is not possible to create `another-example.com` in this zone; you must place it in its own zone.